# How to make an iterator delete node in C

Tags: c, list, iterator, abstract-data-type

I'm doing the `ADT list iterator` in `C`. I have to implement the `void * delete_iterator_list function (list_iterator_t * li)` function. For this.
First, I declared:

```
struct list_iterator {
     node_t *previous;
     node_t *current;
};
```

I initially implemented the following function:

```
void list_iterator_delete (list_t * l, list_iterator_t * li) {
    
     if (list_empty (l) || list_iterator_finish (li)) {
         return;
     }

     struct node * aux_node;

     if (! li-> previous) {
         aux_node = li-> current;
         li-> current = li-> current-> sig;
         l-> prim = li-> current;
     }
     else if (li-> current-> sig == NULL) {
         aux_nodo = li-> current;
         li-> current = li-> current-> sig;
         li-> previous-> sig = li-> current;
     }
     else {
         aux_nodo = li-> current;
         li-> current = li-> current-> sig;
         li-> previous-> sig = li-> current;
     }
    
     free (aux_node);
}
```

Which works correctly. The problem I am having that, is not the function they ask me. I need the function not to receive a `list_t *l`. So, if I don't receive a `list_t *l` within the function I did, when I want to delete the first item in the list, I have no way to link the list back to the current iterator.
I plan to do it with double pointers that might work, since I don't need the reference from the previous one.

But before changing everything, is there any way I can do this function?

Comment: use a pointer to pointer as you are thinking

Comment: This 1000 times.

Comment: https://medium.com/@bartobri/applying-the-linus-tarvolds-good-taste-coding-requirement-99749f37684a